# Service Worker Offline mode

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I created a service worker and it caches all the files and it works offline. What I want is to have on Android the Offline label like in image.

The github demo for that page is [here](https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo). I read the code but didn't found anything that would set that Offline in the left of Url bar.

I cheked multiple websites that have service workers but this is the online one that that I found that has that label.

[image: https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo]

Answer (score 1):

The label is actually not related to service workers. Chrome for Android let's you download web pages for offline use, and the label is shown when you are viewing a downloaded version of a page.

See here for an example: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-save-a-web-page-for-offline-reading-in-Chrome-Android